# Admob disallowed rewarded implementation android

Tags: android, admob

I maked an puzzle game in Android and ! added admob rewarded ad (with video). But I got this in AdMob page :

[image: admob]

Errors : Rewarded Ads - Disallowed Rewarded Implementation, Rewarded Ads - Misleading Disclosure

The codes :

```
AlertDialog.Builder hamlebitti = new AlertDialog.Builder(oyun.this);
hamlebitti.setTitle("Hamle bitti");
hamlebitti.setMessage("Hamle sayınız bitti. Oyuna kaldığınız yerden devam etmek ister misiniz?");
hamlebitti.setPositiveButton("Evet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int id) {

                 if (odulad.isLoaded()) {
                              haki = 1;
                              odulad.show();
                 }

                 if (!odulad.isLoaded()) {
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reklam yüklenemedi. Lütfen daha sonra dene", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          finish();
                          startActivity(new Intent(oyun.this, MainActivity.class));
                  }

             }
             });
     }

@Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

        devamet();

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

        devamet();

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

        devamet();

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {

        devamet();

    }

    public void devamet(){

        oyunhamle = 3;
        hamlebar.setProgress(oyunhamle);
        oyunhamletv.setText("Hamle : " + oyunhamle);

        secilenib.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        secilenibb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        secileniv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        secilenivv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```

How I can resolve this problem?

I need your help. I wait your answers.

Note : I doesn't had a good Englih. Pardon me. I hope you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

The policy of AdMod Rewarded Ads are:

1. The user must know (by your UI) the action will bring a video AD and they must know the exact reward they will get after watching the video AD. The button or icon must show 2 things to your user: **will show video AD** and **reward**.
2. The App can't play the AD automatically. for example, if you play rewarded AD when user exits the app, this is not allowed, because the user doesn't know they will see an AD at leaving.
3. The user must have other options if they doesn't want to watch the video AD.